# J2ME SDK 3.0 WMA Console in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, java-me, sdk, console, wma

Does anyone knows if NetBeans 6.9.1 has the WMA console of J2ME 3.0 SDK?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, WMA console is available in Java ME SDK 3.0, but not in netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

WMA console is available in NetBeans either. Check here:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/229204/JME/Mobile/PushRegistry-emulation-Netbeans

But if you are specific about the version, I should say NetBeans 6.9.1 uses WTK 2.5.2 by default.